# Access token does not have edit scope error

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm using the node.js SDK to access the Vimeo API. I'm attempting to batch edit my albums (Showcases) descriptors and names. I've already created my Vimeo API app and enabled the "Edit" access. Sadly, when I run the code, it returns an error telling me that my access token does not have "edit"\ scope. Below is the code snippet I'm using to send the request:

```
async function setDescriptors(albumPath, newTitle, description) {
  const vimeo = await ensureVimeoClient();//Checks the connection before proceeding
  console.log("Album path: " + albumPath + "\n" + description);
  return await vimeo.request({
        method: 'PATCH',
        path: albumPath,
        params: {
          'name': newTitle,
          'description': description
        }
      }, function (error, body, statusCode, headers) {
        if (error) {
          console.log('There was an error making the request.')
          console.log('Server reported: ' + error)
          return
        }
  })
}
```

Any thoughts on why I'm getting the error? Below is the exact message:
Server reported: Error: {"error":"Your access token does not have the "edit" scope"}

Answer (score 2):

On the developer site where you generate your access token (https://developer.vimeo.com/apps), you need to generate an authenticated access token with 'public', 'private', and 'edit' scopes.

Comment: I already set the access token just as you described. I double checked it.

Comment: for me it worked